# Babel preset with Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron, babeljs

I have an API that uses the babel-preset, so I use this for my API:

```
import express from 'express'; // Not require
import Sequelize from 'sequelize'; // Not require
```

When I run it, it works correctly, but when I package the API inside my Electron app (with Electron Packager) so that the API (server.js) runs when I run my Electron app, I get this error:

```
 import module is not recognized
```

Comment: Uncaught Exception:
     import express from 'express'  ==> error

Comment: [This app uses electron and Babel and import](https://github.com/greggman/MoPho-V). maybe you can find the difference?